# Strategy for logout (JWT)

Tags: jwt

I've implemented JWT in my Spring Boot project. However, the user is only able to log in, but can not really log out.

I've thought about a simple logout implementation: when user clicks the logout button, there's a call to API and the token is saved to `InvalidJWTRepository`. (I'd also remove the cookie from client's browser).

That way, whenever someone is being authenticated and that happens on each call to a secured endpoint, the API would check first, if the token is in the `InvalidJWTRepository`. If it is, then the authentication would be failed, even if the token is actually valid otherwise.